# How do I force `setup.py test` to install dependencies into my `virtualenv`?

Tags: python, virtualenv, setuptools, distribute

In a crusade to make my application `pip`-installable, I'm fighting big fights with `setuptools` and `distribute`. I assume my dependencies are correct, i.e. installing with `pip install myapp` should probably fill the virtual environment correctly. However, I'd like to streamline development while I'm at it, so my goal is to start with an empty `virtualenv` and make `setup.py test` (and later `setup.py develop`, but that's a whole different fight) fill it with all defined dependencies.

And now to my problem: no matter how hard I try, all I get are dependencies installed as `.egg`s in my project directory which is sub-optimal at the very least. I tried creating a new `setuptools` command which would use `pip` (which seems to work, even though awkwardly) but that can't seriously be the solution (subclassing and overriding that is).

So how do I make `setup.py test` fill the `virtualevn` instead of my working directory?

Comment: Can you add the output of your `python setup.py develop` command to the question? When I run that within a virtualenv, it installs dependencies to my virtualenv.

Comment: @Chris: not `tests_requires` dependencies.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By design, you can't make the `tests_requires` or the `setup_requires` entries go into the virtual environment. The idea is to separate what is required for performing tests/setup and what is required to actually use the package being installed. For example, I may require that the "coverage" module be needed for running tests on my package, but it isn't used by any of my code in the package. Therefore, if I didn't have "coverage" in my environment when I go and run tests, I wouldn't want "coverage" to get installed into the environment if my package didn't need it.

Comment: What then is the purpose of tests_requires ?

Comment: In some cases, your tests may have an additional dependency that your package doesn't have in order to perform its tests. A particular example is the "nose" package, which may never get used anywhere else in your project but the tests. This allows you to ship just the package without tests, and not burden your users with unneeded dependcies to make the package work.

Comment: I meant the purpose of test_requires if it is only ever ignored... I had completely missed that it isn't ignored when doing `setup.py tests` / the venv behaviour seems surprising, I understand it shouldn't be default but you should be able to force pip to install of test_requires... http://stackoverflow.com/a/15422703/1240268

Comment: I don't think the behavior is surprising, and I think my explanation makes it quite clear why it would be bad to do otherwise. However, you are free to file a feature request to force install of everything with the setuptools people, but I honestly don't see why that would be desirable.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't explain why running `python setup.py test` wouldn't install the deps on the current venv. If you want to run the tests, it would be desirable to ensure you have all deps to run the tests.

Comment: Why should a venv be treated any differently from a stock environment? If you want test dependencies to always be installed, then put them under "install_requires".

Comment: That's the point it *is* being treated differently (`setup.py test` installs test_requires deps on stock). Anyway we're going round in circles.

Comment: No, it doesn't install it on stock (by install, I mean it gets placed into site-packages). The entire point of test_requires and setup_requires is to prevent contamination of your environment, whether it is stock or venv.

Comment: I would have thought the point of `tests_require` was to force installation of the test dependancies on `setup.py test` but not on `setup.py install`  That, at least to me, seems what should be the desired behavior.

Comment: No, because you did not specify to install the test requirements. You only specified to run the tests. Therefore, running the tests should *not* trigger any actual installations, only to make available those requirements.

Comment: test dependencies should be installable into your venv for development purposes.  the risk of accidentally bundling your development deps seems like fear mongering, respectfully.  CI should be publishing most packages, not humans.  not having dev deps in your python path is painful when you are trying to develop against libs that your editor cannot detect.  code completion, API lookups, linters, etc--all lost when libs are missing from the PYTHONPATH.  i am curious how pydevs workaround this.  do some editors sniff or autoinstall your .eggs, and append the PYTHONPATH magically?

Answer (score -6):

If you are using `setuptools`, you can specify test dependencies using the `tests_require` keyword argument for the `setup` method.

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='your-package-name',
    version='1.0.0',
    author='me',
    author_email='me@mybasement.com',
    install_requires=['Pygments>=1.4'],
    tests_require=['nose'],
    packages=[
        'your_package_name',
    ],
)
```

When you run `python setup.py test`, this will check for `nose` and install it to the currently active `virtualenv` using `pip` if not already available.

Note that this argument will be ignored if you are using `distribute.core.setup` (nor will a `test` command be available).

Comment: It doesn't use pip in my experience.

Comment: This is exactly what the OP did - ending up with .egg dirs all over

Comment: This answer is explicitly incorrect. The [doc](http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#new-and-changed-setup-keywords) states that setuptools will use EasyInstall to install the `tests_require` packages into "the project’s setup directory", whatever that might mean.