# I can't use nosetests individually when I set test_suite="nose.collector" in setup.py

Tags: python, setuptools, nose

This was my earlier question:
[Best practices: how do you list required dependencies in your setup.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15422527/best-practices-how-do-you-list-required-dependencies-in-your-setup-py)

setup.py

```
test_requires = [
    'mock',
    'nose',
    'nose-progressive',
]

# test_suite uses nose so to run tests we should call  ``python setup.py test``
setup(name='lib_name',
      install_requires=install_requires,
      tests_require=test_requires,
      test_suite="nose.collector",
)
```

I now can run `python setup.py test` which will trigger mock, nose and nose-progressive to be installed as egg in the local directory prior to running tests. That's fine with me.

The problem is, I want to run individual test with `nosetests`. That's not possible anymore.

```
(ven)yeukhon@yeukhon:/repo$ which nosetests
/usr/local/bin/nosetests

pip install nose
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): nose in ./nose-1.2.1-py2.7.egg
Cleaning up...
```

What should I do? The global nose will fail my test because of Pyramid's internal settings.

Comment: I'm not a `pip` user, but there is a `--ignore-installed` option which *might* suit your needs.

Comment: @CppLearner, is this still relevant for you now?

Comment: @CppLearner: So how did you solve this problem?